# From Checkbox Into Index Array, Then From Index Array Into Complex?? Array

Tags: php, html, arrays

I am a newbie with coding and I have problem in figuring out my current problem.

Let me explain my situation first.

In my website, users agree to register with their Facebook account. With that, I am able to retrieve all the permitted data, save it in my database and display it in my website's user profile page. Here, the user default profile information is based on users' Facebook. In that page, user able to edit any of their Facebook information and save it (save into my database but will not change the their information in Facebook's site). My point here is, I have created the retrieve codes for displaying the saved data from the database and I do not wish to change that.

Right now, lets get into it. I have my textarea and I want user able to list out their listings in that textarea. With each line marked as list. I created an for it, so I use `explode`. So automatically it is set as index array right? Now, I tried to assign/associate each value with one static key so that it will ease my next step (Retrieving them. Why? I have created the default calling for them in the display page).

So here is my textarea:-

```
<textarea name="languages" placeholder="Your Language of Expertise... 1 Language per Line">
</textarea>
```

After user submitted, their input, it will go to my function page:-

```
$languages = explode("\n", $_POST['languages']);
```

and the array ofcourse will look like this for example:-

```
Array ( 
[0] => Mandarin Chinese
[1] => English 
[2] => French 
[3] => Hokkien 
[4] => Arab
)
```

**I tried to make the array looks like this**:-

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [name] => Mandarin Chinese ) 
[1] => Array ( [name] => English ) 
[2] => Array ( [name] => French ) 
[3] => Array ( [name] => Hokkien ) 
[4] => Array ( [name] => Arab ) 
)
```

**So with that, I can preserve my display callings function** which is like this for example:-

```
$user_lang = Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [name] => Mandarin Chinese )
[1] => Array ( [name] => English )
)

foreach ($user_lang as $lang){
    echo $lang['name'];
}
```

I have tried many method such as using methods such with `array_walk`, `array_merge`, `array_combine`, `array_flip`, `array_fill_keys`, `array_keys` and combination of those. I don't know, maybe for all of those, I used it wrongly. I hope you guys can help me out here. And forgive me for my lack of brain.

Comment: `$languages = array_map(function($x) { return array('name' => $x); }, explode("\n", $_POST['languages']));`

Comment: This has nothing to do with what the tag `facebook` stands for. Please read tag descriptions carefully, and tag appropriately. Tag removed.

Comment: @CBroe Sorry, I thought I've mentioned Facebook, I should include the 'facebook' tag...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the languages and transform each of them into associative arrays like this:

```
foreach ($languages as &$language) {
    $language = [
        'name' => $language
    ];
}
```

The ampersand before `$language` passes the variable by reference. This means that when you change `$language` inside the foreach, the original array value is changed instead of just your newly created `$language` variable.

Comment: Martisen But how am I able to save the foreach data into single array variable?

Comment: After running the foreach you will se that the content of the original `$languages` variable has been updated, and the array now looks like you wanted.

Comment: wow... I wonder how the hell php works like that... It is like css... Do you have any links for me to read how it works like that? Able to update by line stuff like that..... Anyway, thank you for that. It works beautifully.... Have my points!

Comment: The "magic" here is the &-sign. Read more about [passing variables by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) here :)

Comment: Alright... thanks for that... I'll try to understand it (eventhough, right now I don't)....